# Reading Excel File Issue

Tags: c#

I am facing one issue regarding reading excel file (.xls) pro grammatically using c#.Issue is the line below the header row[second row] is missing during reading.I am using below code to read the file. Can anybody tell me how to resolve this issue.

```
string myexceldataquery = "select [Business ID],[Customer Name] from [Sheet1$]";   
string sexcelconnectionstring = @"provider=microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;data source=" + path + ";extended properties=" + "\"excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;\"";
string ssqlconnectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;

string sclearsql = "truncate table " + sqltable;
SqlConnection sqlconn = new SqlConnection(ssqlconnectionstring);
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(sclearsql, sqlconn);
sqlconn.Open();
sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlconn.Close();

OleDbConnection oledbconn = new OleDbConnection(sexcelconnectionstring);
OleDbCommand oledbcmd = new OleDbCommand(myexceldataquery, oledbconn);
oledbconn.Open();
OleDbDataReader dr = oledbcmd.ExecuteReader();
SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(ssqlconnectionstring);
bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = sqltable;
while (dr.Read())
{
    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
}
dr.Close();
oledbconn.Close();
```

Comment: Try with `IMEX=0` in connection string

Comment: Hi Akash, I tried with IMEX=0.But still my issue not resolved.

Comment: I found the reason for this issue.This is due to loop.I changed it to               
              do
                {
                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(dr);
                } while (dr.Read());                                                             
 solved the issue